# Need to store the latitude and longitude values generated from android app into mySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, gps, phpmyadmin

I have made an tracking app in android which successfully generates latitude and longitude

but I need to store lat and long in my external mySQL database using PHP.

I am using value type "decimal(10,7)" for lat and long in DB.

Any ideas how to store lat and long generated from android into my external mySQL database using PHP?

**My PHP CODE**

```
<?php 
        $lat = $_GET['lat'];
        $lng = $_GET['lng'];
        $sender=$_POST['sender'];

 $hostname = 'localhost';
 $username = 'xxxx';
 $password = 'xxxxxxx';

   $conn =  mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Error Please Try Again.'); 

if ($conn) { 

    mysql_select_db("android track", $conn); 


   $query2 = "INSERT INTO coor VALUES(NULL,'$sender','$lat','$lng')"; 

    if (mysql_query($query2, $conn)) 
        echo "Data Insertion Successful"; 
    else 
        echo "Oops".  mysql_error() ; 

  } 

 mysql_close();   
 ?>
```

Comment: What kind of information do you need? How to pass the values from android to PHP or how to store them in the database?

Comment: I need to store the lat and long values from android into mySQL database

Answer (score 1):

You can submit the `mLat`and `mLong`variables to the server using the code below:

```
String storeURL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/yourscript.php?lat=" + mLat + "&long=" + mLong;

URL getURL;
getURL = new URL(storeURL);

URLConnection connection = getURL.openConnection();
connection.connect();

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(getURL.openStream());
OutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();          
byte data[] = new byte[1024];

while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
 output.write(data, 0, count);
}

output.flush();
output.close();
input.close();

String downloadResult = output.toString();
Log.i("LOG", downloadResult); //Your php-script can, for example, "echo("OK");" if the storing was successful
```

You still need to take care of error-handling (no network connection, etc.), of course.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried your code but still could not get lat and long saved in DB.

Comment: Do you have the php-side of your code working? I.e. do you have a PHP-script that takes values from the `GET`-variables (`?lat=&long=`) and stores it in a DB?

Comment: Thanks! Have you tested the PHP code in a browser (by simply entering `http://yourdomain.com/yourscript.php?lat=3.45555&lng=1.3344&sender=x`) to make sure that it works, independently of the Android-component?

Comment: Thanks for your support! 
No it is giving error on line 3 and on line 4
and at the end displaying 
"OopsIncorrect decimal value: '' for column 'long' at row 1"

Comment: @hd1 now it says "OopsData truncated for column 'long' at row 1"

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Ok, few things before I rewrite your code...

1. You are opening yourself up to SQL Injection attacks, because you
   aren't using prepared statements.
2. The mysql PHP interface is deprecated and mysqli or PDO ought to be
   used instead.
3. I'm assuming you're passing the NULL for a primary key on the coordinates table. Don't
   do that, instead, mark it as `auto increment` and specify your columns explicitly in 
   SQL.
4. What is the create table statement for the coordinates table? Paste the results of `SHOW
   CREATE TABLE coordinates` into your question. I suspect you're passing a value of `null`
   in a column that's a `primary key` and can never be null.

Comment: Still no progress, I cannot still store lat  and long values in db

Comment: I'm still not seeing the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE coordinates` @CoolJCoolie